# How to stop edges from crossing directly over text icon

Tags: canvas, vis.js, vis.js-network

These are my edge settings

```
        from: fromNodeId,
        to: toNodeId,
        arrowStrikethrough: false,
        arrows: {
            to: {
                enabled: true
            },
            from: {
                enabled: true,
                type: "circle",
            }
        },
        color: {
            color: "black",
        }
```

Based on the screenshot attached, it seems to know not to cross "box" node and just runs through the text node for some reason. (Since I needed the diagram to show up, I used "beforeDrawing" on network and used CanvasRenderingContext2D to draw the image in the background). By the way, the nodes dimension is set correctly on text. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4Eoy.png)

Is there any settings or other way to get the edge crossing text node to show up in a similar fashion to the box node?

I tried to adjust various edges and nodes setting to no avail at this point.